# Return a tuple containing the number of interior nodes and the number of leaves

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary-tree

How would I return a tuple containing the number of interior nodes and the number of leaves?
Below is what I got so far, but it's doesn't seem to be working properly.

Also, does anyone know of a good website where I can learn binary trees and recursion with problem sets for more practice?

```
class BTNode:
    '''Node in binary tree'''

    def __init__(self, value, left, right):
        '''
        Create new BTNode with value and possible children left and right'''

        self.value, self.left, self.right = value, left, right

    def count_nodes(n:'BTNode') -> (int, int):
        '''
        Return a tuple containing the number of interior nodes and the number of
        leaves in the tree rooted at n, or (0,0) if n is None.
        '''

        if not n:
            return (0,0)

        else:
            left_internal, left_leaves = count_nodes(n.left)
            right_internal, right_leaves = count_nodes(n.right)
            internal, leaf = (1 if n.left or n.right else 0,
                              1 if not n.left and not n.right else 0)

        return (left_internal + right_internal + internal, 
                left_leaves + right_leaves + leaf)
```

Comment: Please also show what it *actually outputs* or returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class BTNode:
    '''Node in binary tree'''

    def __init__(self, value, left=None, right=None):
        '''
        Create new BTNode with value and possible children left and right
        '''
        self.value, self.left, self.right = value, left, right

    def count_nodes(self):
        '''
        Return a tuple containing the number of interior nodes and the number of
        leaves in the tree rooted at n, or (0,0) if n is None.
        '''
        if self.left is None and self.right is None:
            # leaf
            return (0, 1)
        else:
            # internal node
            left_nodes,  left_leaves  = (0, 0) if self.left  is None else self.left.count_nodes()
            right_nodes, right_leaves = (0, 0) if self.right is None else self.right.count_nodes()
            return (left_nodes + 1 + right_nodes, left_leaves + right_leaves)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I don't understand the base case returning (0, 1) though. Can you please elaborate your answer?

Comment: @muros: if it has no left- or right-descendants, it is a leaf. Therefore it returns (0 internal nodes, 1 leaf).